# Quickly and smoothly flick between images in WPF using a timer?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I'd like to display a random image every 0.2 seconds on my WPF application.

I've tried using the various .NET timers to achieve this, and the response isn't brilliant - it works, but it tends to stutter, or one image will be there noticeably longer than the rest.

What's the best approach here / what am I missing? I'm assuming it's either the System.Timer or the Random() that's the issue. Is there a better timer to use>

I pre-load all of the images as BitmapSource properties when I create the PlayerViewModels.

I've posted the code below:

```
    private const int TIMER_INTERVAL = 200;
    private Timer _timer;
    private static Random _random = new Random();
    public List<PlayerViewModel> Players { get; set; }
    public PlayerViewModel CurrentPlayer { get; set; }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Players = new PlayerInfoParser().Players.Select(x=> new PlayerViewModel(x)).ToList();
        CurrentPlayer = GetRandomPlayer();
        _timer = new Timer(UpdatePlayer, null, 0, TIMER_INTERVAL);
    }

    private void UpdatePlayer(object state)
    {
        CurrentPlayer = GetRandomPlayer();
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPlayer"); // Update View
    }

    private PlayerViewModel GetRandomPlayer()
    {
        var randomNumber = _random.Next(Players.Count);
        return (Players[randomNumber]);
    }
```

Comment: Your `GetRandomPlayer` method may return the same `PlayerViewModel` instance as the previous time it was called, that might explain why images sometimes *appear* to stay on the screen longer than they should. At minimum I'd put code in there to ensure you get a different instance with each call (ie. have a field to store the "current" random number, and keep looping until it differs).

Comment: Also, how are you creating the `BitmapSource` values in your `PlayerViewModel`? Might be worth posting that code in your question.

Comment: Your first thought was absolutely spot on, Steven. I was just lacking a bit of common sense! Should have been obvious seeing as I'm dealing with a small data set.